# Google AMP site still showing after deleted WordPress plugin

Tags: amp-html

I need Google to reindex my site. I have deleted the AMP plugins, including the Google AMP plugin, but it's still showing in search results. I put a redirect from https://rainbowriting.com/amp to https://rainbowriting.com but it's still loading the pretty much "blank" page which only has an arrow leading to the real page, and I need to know how to get rid of this soon before I lose SERPs positions. My email is karen (at) rainbowriting.com (only one "w" in rainbowriting)

Answer (score 0):

Your content is cached in the AMP cache, so deleting the actual AMP page isn't enough to tell Google it should throw it out.

You need to follow the steps provided by Google here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/remove-amp